# Set MenuItem onPressed actions Android actionbar? Preferably programmatic

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have a menu created without XML in my class files which are just icons. I'd like to remove the blue square/rectangle highlight shown when the `MenuItem` is pressed, and instead just change the color of the item (by just showing the same drawable with a new color, from the `res`).

My menu is as follows, is what I'm trying to achieve possible? I know it probably is via XML but that's not what I want.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, "BACK").setIcon(android.R.drawable.back);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return true;
}
```

I'm using ActionBarSherlock in case that changes anything.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: If replacing the image isn't possible, I'll settle for just stopping the highlight from appearing. But bonus marks for the image swap :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to remove the blue square/rectangle highlight shown when the
>   `MenuItem` is pressed

You can use [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator) in order to identify and replace/modify the assets you need (try modifying the value of *Accent color*).

> and instead just change the color of the item (by just showing the
>   same drawable with a new color, from the `res`).

You should simply use the two colored version (default and pressed) of your image within a specific [XML selector](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#selector-element) to be used as resource for your icon.